# Django ModelViewSet It takes a long time to display requests on the screen

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I measured how many seconds it takes to prepare the data for the request, 4 seconds came out.
In the browser, the request is displayed only after 20 seconds. What could this be related to?

Product table has about 100,000 records. Database queries are executed in 0.5 seconds

views.py

```
class ProductImproveView(ModelViewSet):

 filterset_class = ProductFilter

 serializer_class = ProductListingSerializerLightImproved

 def get_queryset(self):
     return {
         'qs': Product.objects.all()[:30],
         'count': Product.objects.all().count()
     }
 
 
 def list(self, request, processed_queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):

     start_time = datetime.now()
     
     result = self.get_queryset()
     queryset = result['qs']
     count = result['count']
     serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
     
     
     d = serializer.data

     g = JsonResponse({
         'count': count,
         'next': 'nd',
         'results': d
     })
     print(g.content)
     
     print(datetime.now() - start_time)  # 4 seconds

     return g
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products-improve', ProductImproveView, basename='products')
urlpatterns = []

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

serializer.py

```
class ProductListingSerializerLightImproved(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store_title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    store_logo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_new = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    stock = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'slug', 'is_new', 'discount', 'rating', 'rating', 'store_title', 'store_logo', \
                  'category', 'image', 'stock', 'price']

    def get_price(self, obj):
        return PriceSerializer(obj.variations.order_by('order')[:1][0]).data

    def get_store_title(self, obj):
        return obj.store.title

    def get_store_logo(self, obj):
        return "{}{}".format('https://pasimol.s3.amazonaws.com/', obj.store.logo)

    def get_category(self, obj):
        return CategorySerializerLight(obj.category, many=True).data

    def get_image(self, obj):
        return S3ImageSerializerLight(obj.variations.all()[:1][0].images.all(), many=True).data

    def get_rating(self, obj):
        return decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0, 50)) / 10

    def get_is_new(self, obj):
        new_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        delta = timezone.now() - obj.created_at
        if delta > new_delta:
            return False
        return True

    def get_stock(self, obj):
        return obj.stock
```

Comment: Poor internet connection? What does the network tab in the dev tools show?

Comment: I work at localhost. Other models work much faster

Comment: How many records are in the Product table?

Comment: Also please provide the `ProductListingSerializerLightImproved` serializer's code

Comment: The product table has about 100,000 records

Comment: You are facing the [N + 1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping), I guess that the view makes at least 121+ queries.